How to display one object of api response in the cell at a time using tableview cells in

I have gotten some success to get to the end of the first nested array but now I have difficulties in shifting to next index Eg:- I am at
{
"choice" : 1742,
"assessment" : 133,
"id" : 865,
"title" : "How good is your spice tolerance?",
"choices" : [
                  ],
                  "description" : "",
                  "type" : "rating",
                  "creator" : 5
                }

I want to go to
{
"choice" : null,
"assessment" : 133,
"id" : 866,
"title" : "Describe the kind of stories you enjoy watching",
"choices" : [
  ],
  "description" : "",
  "type" : "free_text",
  "creator" : 5
}

how do I achieve this.
{
  "status" : true,
  "code" : 200,
  "results" : [
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 863,
      "title" : "What do you like to eat duing a movie?",
      "choices" : [
        {
          "id" : 1738,
          "title" : "Popcorn",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 863,
          "questions" : [
            {
              "choice" : 1738,
              "assessment" : 133,
              "id" : 864,
              "title" : "What flavours of popcorn do you like?",
              "choices" : [
                {
                  "id" : 1739,
                  "title" : "Caramel",
                  "nas_class" : "c1",
                  "question" : 864,
                  "questions" : [

                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id" : 1740,
                  "title" : "Cheese",
                  "nas_class" : "c1",
                  "question" : 864,
                  "questions" : [

                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id" : 1741,
                  "title" : "Tomato",
                  "nas_class" : "c1",
                  "question" : 864,
                  "questions" : [

                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id" : 1742,
                  "title" : "Chilli",
                  "nas_class" : "c1",
                  "question" : 864,
                  "questions" : [
                    {
                      "choice" : 1742,
                      "assessment" : 133,
                      "id" : 865,
                      "title" : "How good is your spice tolerance?",
                      "choices" : [

                      ],
                      "description" : "",
                      "type" : "rating",
                      "creator" : 5
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "description" : "",
              "type" : "multi_select",
              "creator" : 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1743,
          "title" : "Nachos",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 863,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1744,
          "title" : "Chips",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 863,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "single_select",
      "creator" : 5
    },
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 866,
      "title" : "Describe the kind of stories you enjoy watching",
      "choices" : [

      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "free_text",
      "creator" : 5
    },
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 867,
      "title" : "Sign here to indicate that you consent selling of your data",
      "choices" : [

      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "signature",
      "creator" : 5
    },
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 868,
      "title" : "Upload a picture of your driving license",
      "choices" : [

      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "file_upload",
      "creator" : 5
    },
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 869,
      "title" : "Give your opinion",
      "choices" : [
        {
          "id" : 1745,
          "title" : "Bad",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 869,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1746,
          "title" : "Poor",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 869,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1747,
          "title" : "Good",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 869,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1748,
          "title" : "Excellent",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 869,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "single_select",
      "creator" : 5
    }
  ],
  "msg" : "Success"
}

I have added the image for the UI.
I have tried this link for the answer :- Move collectionView on button click (Swift). But I have nested json structure it is not working for me. I have tried to get the json into a dictionary.
This is the code I have implemented :-

func preorderTraversalDFS(_ roots: [ResultsQuestions]?) -> [Int: TreeItem] { // Get the json response in dictionary
        guard let roots = roots else {
            return [:]
        }
        
        var result: [Int: TreeItem] = [:]
        
        for root in roots {
            let treeItem = TreeItem(id: root.id,
                                    title: root.title,
                                    description: root.description,
                                    type: root.type,
                                    assessment: root.assessment,
                                    choices: convertChoices(root.choices),
                                    choice: root.choice,
                                    creator: root.creator)
            result[root.id] = treeItem
            if let choices = root.choices {
                for choice in choices {
                    let subTree = preorderTraversalDFS(choice.questions)
                    subTree.forEach { (key, value) in
                        result[key] = value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        arrayDict = result
        return result
    }


extension viewController : UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objResponseQuestions.count // decoded json stored in objResponseQuestions
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: nestedAssessmentTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? nestedAssessmentTableViewCell else { return nestedAssessmentTableViewCell() }
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

            cell.optionsLabel.text = objResponseQuestions?[indexPath.row].choices?[indexPath.row].title
                      
            return cell
}
}


// MARK: - Choice
struct Choice: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let nasClass: String
    let question: Int
    let questions: [ResultsQuestions]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, title
        case nasClass = "nasClass"
        case question, questions
    }
}

// MARK: - Result
struct ResultsQuestions: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, description, type: String
    let assessment: Int
    let choices: [Choice]?
    let choice: Int?
    let creator: Int
} // This is the data strut I have loaded my json response into 
    

but it is not going inside of the nested tree array structure.

The standard way to deal with JSON in Swift is to decode it into a Decodable struct. I wouldn't be messing around with trees or dictionaries.

@Paulw11 I have decode the json but want to know how to populate the tableview cell one at a time. to the desired screenshot from the data I am receiving

If that is your question, then you should show the relevant code. What data structure have you loaded the data into (and don't say a dictionary, it is going to be horrible to work with)?  What code do you have to render the tableview you have shown?

@Paulw11 I have added the tableView implementation and the struct in which I have loaded the json from api. From the struct ResultsQuestions I am making a dictionary and then as referred to the answer (mentioned in Link) trying to populate the tableview cell. But I have no success to retrieve the data which is nested (as shown in the response json)

You need to design your layout. You have multiple levels here. You probably need a cell that can display the various options. It will need to have a variable height probably.  If UIKit isn't mandated I would use SwiftUI. This would be much simpler with declarative ui

@Paulw11 what should I search for if I am trying to make it in swiftUI . My whole project is in uikit.

You can do it in UIKit. Unfortunately there isn't a simple answer. You are going to have to spend some time designing your UI and creating the various views and cells you need.

@Paulw11,  well it is what it is right, I have some work cut out for me on this one. But if you find anything helpful for me please add anything that I can try. Thank you.

@Paulw11 I have received some success to reach the end of the nested array but from there I want to make a jump to the next node i.e second index of the array please refer me to any article that can help
