Working with nested arrays, accessing next array after I have reached the end of the first nested arrays end element
I want to access the elements of this JSON:
{
  "status" : true,
  "code" : 200,
  "results" : [
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 863,
      "title" : "What do you like to eat duing a movie?",
      "choices" : [
        {
          "id" : 1738,
          "title" : "Popcorn",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 863,
          "questions" : [
            {
              "choice" : 1738,
              "assessment" : 133,
              "id" : 864,
              "title" : "What flavours of popcorn do you like?",
              "choices" : [
                {
                  "id" : 1739,
                  "title" : "Caramel",
                  "nas_class" : "c1",
                  "question" : 864,
                  "questions" : [

                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id" : 1740,
                  "title" : "Cheese",
                  "nas_class" : "c1",
                  "question" : 864,
                  "questions" : [

                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id" : 1741,
                  "title" : "Tomato",
                  "nas_class" : "c1",
                  "question" : 864,
                  "questions" : [

                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id" : 1742,
                  "title" : "Chilli",
                  "nas_class" : "c1",
                  "question" : 864,
                  "questions" : [
                    {
                      "choice" : 1742,
                      "assessment" : 133,
                      "id" : 865,
                      "title" : "How good is your spice tolerance?",
                      "choices" : [

                      ],
                      "description" : "",
                      "type" : "rating",
                      "creator" : 5
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "description" : "",
              "type" : "multi_select",
              "creator" : 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1743,
          "title" : "Nachos",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 863,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1744,
          "title" : "Chips",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 863,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "single_select",
      "creator" : 5
    },
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 866,
      "title" : "Describe the kind of stories you enjoy watching",
      "choices" : [

      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "free_text",
      "creator" : 5
    },
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 867,
      "title" : "Sign here to indicate that you consent selling of your data",
      "choices" : [

      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "signature",
      "creator" : 5
    },
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 868,
      "title" : "Upload a picture of your driving license",
      "choices" : [

      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "file_upload",
      "creator" : 5
    },
    {
      "choice" : null,
      "assessment" : 133,
      "id" : 869,
      "title" : "Give your opinion",
      "choices" : [
        {
          "id" : 1745,
          "title" : "Bad",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 869,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1746,
          "title" : "Poor",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 869,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1747,
          "title" : "Good",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 869,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        },
        {
          "id" : 1748,
          "title" : "Excellent",
          "nas_class" : "c1",
          "question" : 869,
          "questions" : [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "description" : "",
      "type" : "single_select",
      "creator" : 5
    }
  ],
  "msg" : "Success"
}

I am able to access the first array at index 0, and can reach the end of the nested array but need to shift to the index 1 and so on after I reach to the end of the n array elements. How do I make it happen? I have added the struct to the the question as well.

// MARK: - TreeItem
struct TreeItem {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var type: String
    var assessment: Int
    var choices: [ChoiceItem]?
    var choice: Int?
    var creator: Int
    var isSelected : String?
}

// MARK: - ChoiceItem
struct ChoiceItem {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var nasClass: String
    var question: Int
    var questions: [TreeItem]?
}

Using this functions for converting the n array tree into the nested array. I am new to nested arrays.
// Fetching json from api and storing it in the structs 

 func fetchData() {
        showLoader()
        AssessmentQuestionsViewModel.getAssessmentQuestions(for: assessmentID) { result in
            self.hideLoader()
            switch result {
            case .Success(let questions):
                self.objResponseQuestions = questions.results
                self.arrayObjResultQuestionsCount = (self.objResponseQuestions?.count ?? 0)
                if let assesmentDataValue = self.objResponseQuestions {
                    self.treeArray = self.convertTreeToArray(assesmentDataValue)
                    self.setData()
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            case.CustomError(let errorMessage):
                self.view.showTost("The Assessment Details are not available at the moment")
            }
        }
    }


// function used to convert the nested n array tree to a array of struct TreeItem
func convertTreeToArray(_ roots: [ResultsQuestions]?) -> [TreeItem] {
        guard let roots = roots else {
            return []
        }
        
        var result: [TreeItem] = []
        
        for root in roots {
            result.append(contentsOf: convertNodeToArray(root))
        }
        
//        print(result)
        return result
    }

    func convertNodeToArray(_ node: ResultsQuestions) -> [TreeItem] {
        var result: [TreeItem] = [TreeItem(id: node.id,
                                           title: node.title,
                                           description: node.description,
                                           type: node.type,
                                           assessment: node.assessment,
                                           choices: convertChoices(node.choices),
                                           choice: node.choice,
                                           creator: node.creator ?? 0,
                                           isSelected: nil)]
        
        if let choices = node.choices {
            for choice in choices {
                if let questions = choice.questions {
                    result += questions.flatMap { convertNodeToArray($0) }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return result
    }

    func convertChoices(_ choices: [Choice]?) -> [ChoiceItem]? {
        guard let choices = choices else {
            return nil
        }
        return choices.map { choice in
            return ChoiceItem(id: choice.id,
                              title: choice.title,
                              nasClass: choice.nasClass,
                              question: choice.question,
                              questions: choice.questions?.flatMap { convertNodeToArray($0) })
        }
    }

// As mention in the comments about another link. The UI screenshot is present there. 

// Next button for getting the next array index 

 
    @IBAction func nextScreenButtonActions(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if isNextQuestionAvailable == true {
            
            firstTreeArray?.choices?.removeAll()
            firstTreeArray?.type.removeAll()
            firstTreeArray?.choices?.removeAll()
            
            firstTreeArray = newChoiceItemSelected?.questions?.first
            
            self.questionLabel.text = firstTreeArray?.title ?? ""
            self.tempQuestionNumber = self.tempQuestionNumber + 1
            self.questionNumberLabel.text = "Q" + " " + String(describing: self.tempQuestionNumber)
            
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            
            //All Next choices in the array depth are nil as they should move to another array
            firstTreeArray?.choices?.removeAll()
            firstTreeArray?.type.removeAll()
            firstTreeArray?.choices?.removeAll()
            
            self.firstTreeArray = self.treeArray[newIndexForTreeArray]
            self.questionLabel.text = firstTreeArray?.title ?? ""
            
            tableView.reloadData()
            if arrayObjResultQuestionsCount >= newIndexForTreeArray {
                newIndexForTreeArray += 1
                self.tempQuestionNumber = self.tempQuestionNumber + 1
                self.questionNumberLabel.text = "Q" + " " + String(describing: self.tempQuestionNumber)
            } else if arrayObjResultQuestionsCount == newIndexForTreeArray {
                print("No increment in the value of the count. ")
                self.tempQuestionNumber = arrayObjResultQuestionsCount
                self.questionNumberLabel.text = "Q" + " " + String(describing: self.tempQuestionNumber)
            } else if arrayObjResultQuestionsCount == 1 {
                print("No increment in the value of the count. ")
                self.tempQuestionNumber = arrayObjResultQuestionsCount
                self.questionNumberLabel.text = "Q" + " " + String(describing: self.tempQuestionNumber)
            }
        }

    }


// UITableView cell for row at function , using closure to check if the nested array is empty or no. 


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var AssessmentDataTypes = firstTreeArray?.type

   case "multi_select" :
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: nestedAssessmentTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? nestedAssessmentTableViewCell else { return nestedAssessmentTableViewCell() }
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
            
            cell.optionsLabel.text = firstTreeArray?.choices?[indexPath.row].title
            cell.optionsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "TickUnselected"), for: .normal)
//            self.nextScreenButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            cell.optionsButtonPressed = {[weak self ] in
                guard let self = self else {return}
                newChoiceItemSelected = firstTreeArray?.choices?[indexPath.row]
                
                if newChoiceItemSelected?.questions?.isEmpty == true {
                    isNextQuestionAvailable = false
                } else {
                    firstTreeArray?.isSelected = "True"
                    
                    isNextQuestionAvailable = true
                }
            }

            return cell
        case "single_select":
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: nestedAssessmentTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? nestedAssessmentTableViewCell else { return nestedAssessmentTableViewCell() }
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
            
            cell.optionsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "TickUnselected"), for: .normal)
            
            cell.optionsLabel.text = firstTreeArray?.choices?[indexPath.row].title
            
//            self.nextScreenButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            cell.optionsButtonPressed = {[weak self ] in
                guard let self = self else {return}
//                print(indexPath.row)
                newChoiceItemSelected = firstTreeArray?.choices?[indexPath.row]
                
                if newChoiceItemSelected?.questions?.isEmpty == true {
                    isNextQuestionAvailable = false

                } else if newChoiceItemSelected?.questions == nil {
                    isNextQuestionAvailable = false
                }  else {

                    firstTreeArray?.isSelected = "True"
                    
                    isNextQuestionAvailable = true
                }

            }
            return cell

 default:
            break
        }
 
        return UITableViewCell()

}

How can I go to the next index of the array?

To access the elements of your JSON data, first decode the json data into the appropriate models, using let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(....).
To get the correct models, simply copy and paste the json data into  https://app.quicktype.io/ .
All the Swift model structs will be generated for you. From that it is easy to access any part of those models.

I assume the decoding works as expected but I am not sure I understand what you’re trying to convert the decoded types into and why but don’t you need a bunch of nested for loops when converting possibly inside a function that you call recursively when reaching more questions.

@workingdogsupportUkraine , I have decoded it using the link given and want to show it in my uitableview cell.

@JoakimDanielson ,  I want to show this design in a uitableview cell and I have posted a question about it, Link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78446947/how-to-display-one-object-of-api-response-in-the-cell-at-a-time-using-tableview?noredirect=1#comment138302664_78446947, Since it did not recieve any answer I am trying to decode the problem into smaller chucks and solve it , this is I have recieved some success and this is another problem I am stuck on and need some help with.

Ok but it’s not clear to me exactly what kind of help you need,  that is what it is you are trying to achieve. Showing something in a table view cell is a pretty vague description.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issues, see: Minimal code.  Currently you show some disconnected bits of code without any purpose that does not use uitableview.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I have update it with minimal code

@JoakimDanielson sorry as I might fall short on explanation of what I need , I want to know how can I access the next index elements in the array when I have chosen an option to the answer which doen't have a nested QnA on selection.

Please check https://github.com/immanaro2497/MovieQuestions. I have created a sample.
I have changed each tree item to have only question and choices. The questions inside the choices are created as new tree item.
The originalQuestions variable is for getting the original data without any user changes.
The questionsWithAnswer variable is the list of questions with user interacted data. you can add new properties if you want. This list will update based on the choice selected and other user interactions(currently implemented only for choice selection).
